# Progress bar of video does not allow click event of other button

Tags: android, video-streaming, progress-bar

I have developed module that play video in android application. If you see the attached image the video is playing fine. But when progress bar shows up, I won't able to click on Skip video button. If progress bar disappears

Link for image: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_xgCwfb-GVmX0psNzZXM09tVEU/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the code:

```
private VideoView video;
public static MediaController mediaController;
private Button viewReadingsButton;


if (isViewReadingEnabled) {
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams vparams = video
                                .getLayoutParams();
                        vparams.height = 480;
                        vparams.width = 800;
                        video.setLayoutParams(vparams);
                    }

                    video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    if (isViewReadingEnabled) {
                        Log.i(TAGOXY,
                                "In BaseActivity:video():viewReadingsButton visible");
                        viewReadingsButton
                                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.video_skip_bg);
                        viewReadingsButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    video.refreshDrawableState();

                    // MediaController mediaController = new
                    // MediaController(BaseActivity.this);
                    mediaController = new MediaController(BaseActivity.this);
                    mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
                    mediaController.setPadding(200, 0, 0, 200);

                    // set the controllers to the video view
                    video.setMediaController(mediaController);
                    Log.i(TAGOXY,
                            "In BaseActivity:video():after MediaController");

                    video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(loadVideoFileName));
                    Log.i(TAGOXY, "In BaseActivity:video():after setVideoURI");

                    // start the video
                    video.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending large amount of time, I found that it is not possible with my current code.

Since we are using Web view to load HTML pages, now we are using plugin to play video in HTML page itself. Over there, I am able to achieve this desired functionality.